# Can the Euphonium Unbound item be turned off after use?

Tags: genshin-impact

Patch 2.4 introduced the Euphonium Unbound furniture for the Serenitea Pot feature. By placing the furniture in a realm layout, players can switch the default background music for that area to one of the music disk they acquired.

Yet apparently there is no way to turn off the device after you switch it on without having to edit the area layout and removing the gadget altogether.

It is worth noticing that the player cannot achieve a "reset to default" effect  by selecting any of the available tunes in the device. This is because the layout default state [plays a different tune based on the time of the day](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Emerald_Peak_Soundtracks) while the device only allows to select a single tune to be played at any time.

Is there any way to "shut down" the device that does not involve editing the realm layout to remove-read the furniture in order to reset it to the original state? This is especially important now since the furniture placement function is undergoing maintenance with no estimated ETA, so it is currently impossible for anyone to remove a Euphonium Unbound furniture that was already placed and activated.